# Function to return a specific value in a given input range

Tags: c

I need to Write a function in C language whose output with respect to input should like this:

[image]

The above table is just for an example. The input is not limited to 25, and also the number of inputs in a particular range is `X` instead of 5. I cannot figure out how to do this?

Right now I don't have enough time write a better question ;). Please edit it if you found any mistake.

Comment: checkout how to make a string to an int and read about the modulus operator and you will likely only need a few lines

Comment: Why the down votes?? It is the part of my Quiz paper.

Comment: you get down-votes because you did not show any effort in solving this yourself. What have you tried so far?

Comment: because SO is not a 'write my (home)work for me' page -- its for when you have a particular problem :)

Comment: @Daij-Djan: Please use the term _remainder operator_ instead of the (incorrect and misleading for negative arguments) term _modulus operator_. The operator **%** does not form a _ring_ over the integers with standard multiplication and division.

Comment: It's `(x + 4) / 5` if the input `x` is an integer...

Comment: @Daij-Djan: My pleasure. I use this operator frequently, and one of my (few) peeves with C# is that it perpetuates K&R's mistake by retaining the **C** definition of this operator. It results in some very simple math becoming some really ugly code.

Comment: Right now I don't have time to answer your question.

Comment: "Why the down votes??" -- Because of low-quality suckage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int f(int x, int X){
    return (x + (X-1))/X;
}
```

Comment: Did you  read the question *carefully*?

Answer (score 1):

```
int func(int x)
{
    if(x%5 == 0)
        return x/5;
    else
        return x/5 + 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about an array of structs along

```
struct range {
    int lo, hi, result;
}
```

Ask the user for X, then allocate an array with X instances of this struct,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct range *array = malloc (X * sizeof *array);
```

Now loop over X table rows asking for the lo, hi and result. The rest is left as an exercise...